# How can I designate "internal" modules in my cabal package

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm using cabal to help organize my dependencies, build process, and testing for a small Haskell project I'm working on. The current cabal file contains lines such as the following:

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Project.Exposed1
                       , Project.Exposed2
                         -- pretty please don't use below modules
                       , TestingUtilityFunctions
                       , GenericUtilityFunctions

  other-modules:       Convenient submodule for responsibility separation
                       , Another one

executable E1
  -- relies on Project for both Project.Exposed1 AND GenericUtilityFunctions

testsuite T2
  -- relies on Project for both Project.Exposed2 AND TestingUtilityFunctions
```

I need to keep `TestingUtilityFunctions` and `GenericUtilityFunctions` exposed because they appear in `E1` and `T2`. However, they shouldn't be present in the library since the library's functionality is not to provide generic utility functions (which I change as I see fit), but to provide the interface exposed by `Project.Exposed*` modules.

Is there any way to make a "private" library (or several, to minimize dependency over-inclusion) which I can use inside my package but across executables and testsuites?

Comment: Is it important that `GenericUtilityFunctions` and `TestingUtilityFunctions` come from the library? I mean, one could imagine building your executable and test suite with their own internal copy of the library and *not* have an actual dependency on the library; this would increase the compile time significantly but would ease the need to expose internal stuff. I probably wouldn't squint too hard if this were needed for the test suite, though if even your executable needs access to internal stuff, that's probably a bad sign that your public API isn't exciting enough.

Comment: (...and if that approach sounds appealing to you, I'd be happy to write it up in enough detail to qualify as an answer.)

Comment: @DanielWagner That answer looks like it takes care of everything I requested in the question, though unfortunately the compilation time is a pretty serious concern, mainly because of the testing dependencies, which take a while.

I think it's worth posting as an answer since it addresses what the question wants.

Comment: @DanielWagner It's actually a bit more complicated - I would agree that it's an API issue if the executable needs access to internals. What's really going on is the following:

The library provides generic functionality X.
The executable provides an important instantiation of X, Y.
Y contains some boring business logic that is not too complex but requires a decent amount of code - it is easily testable and has much to gain from being unit tested. If I want to test Y I need to include Y in the library so that it can be tested...

Comment: It sounds like you just need a single module to be shared between the executable and test suite, and that module doesn't need access to library internals. That to me screams "not part of the library" -- just a file you write once and import in both the executable and test suite. That module will have to get compiled twice, but that probably isn't such a big hit -- certainly smaller than compiling the library three times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One approach, used in `containers`, is to use CPP to expose some bindings conditionally, depending on whether or not a test build is being run.

The correct approach, in most cases, is to *expose* your internals module, with a name like `Blah.Blah.Internal`, which lets your users play games behind your back while solemnly (but implicitly) warning them that they'd better be careful and that they can't rely on anything in there staying the same from version to version.

Comment: Considering the scope of the project, it seems like using an internal module is probably the way to go, especially since I don't have another convincing reason to use CPP. Unfortunately this doesn't solve the over-inclusion of dependencies problem.